# How is a morphism different from a function

Tags: functions, category-theory, morphism

How is a morphism (from category theory) different from a function?

Intuitive explanation + maths would be great

Comment: I think this gives a decent explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism

The key thing that makes a morphism more than/different from in the category theory case is that the 'map' preserves some structure of the domain when you move to the codomain. The morphism of category theory are a generalization of that idea.

Comment: @JustinBenfield: The opposite seems to be true: "particularly in category theory, a morphism is a structure-preserving map from one mathematical structure to another one of the same type." So, the map does not have to be structure-preserving, but the morphism is structure-preserving.

Comment: See the 2nd paragraph of the page I linked, it explains in what way Morphisms in category theory generalize the concept as it appears in other areas of mathematics.

Comment: A morphism is more or less whatever you want it to be. That's the point. It's a very general definition that permits any kind of distinguished/especially interesting way of transforming or relating objects of your universe, fuzzily speaking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $G$ is a group, there is a famous example that constructs a category in which morphisms are *not* functions: you take it to consist of a single object called "$\bullet$" and *state* that the morphisms (of $\bullet$ to $\bullet$, because there is no other object available) are *the elements of $G$*. Check for yourself that all the properties defining a category are verified by this (admittedly strange) example.

Comment: Doesn't a morphism need an origin object and a destination object? How can morphisms be the elements of a random group G, which may not satisfy the property?

Comment: @octavian: They do, and they are all $\bullet$.

Comment: I updated my previous comment

Comment: @octavian: *"[They] may not satisfy the property"* - what property? As I've said (don't be lazy, check them!) all the properties are satisfied. Your difficulties with this example arise from thinking in terms of [concrete categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category). Stop doing this, and everything else will follow. Think of morphisms as just abstract, formal arrows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure but here is my thought. I think that is a generalization of relations (at least that the idea stemmed from them). A relation is a subset of the cartesian product of two sets, consisting of couples of elements belonging to the two sets. A relation is more general (or generic perhaps) than a function; functions are relations satisfying the condition that the elements in the domain have at most one image element in the codomain. You could picture both relations and functions with a set of arrows pointing from an element to the other from domain to codomain (which is exactly what we are thought to do in elementary math courses).
A morphism in the categorical sense does pretty much the same (and indeed is also called an arrow), except for the fact that relations are defined on sets whereas in categories you work with classes and for the fact that a relation establishes a specific "set of arrows" whereas a morphism refers to all possibile arrows between two distinct objects.
Also, a Functor seems to me to do pretty much the same as a "standard" morphism (one not in the categorical sense).
My feeling is that, in categories, switching the names morphism and functor would have generated less confusion. Functor sounds like a parent of function, though not being the same, whereas morphism would be called the same.

Answer (score 0):

In algebraic geometry, functions and morphisms are both important concepts, but they serve different purposes and have different definitions:

1. **Functions**:

   - In algebraic geometry, a function typically refers to a regular function or rational function on an algebraic variety.
   - A regular function on an algebraic variety (V) is a function that is locally given by a quotient of polynomials. It's defined on an open subset of (V), where it behaves smoothly.
   - A rational function on an algebraic variety (V) is a function that is locally given by a quotient of polynomials, but it may have poles where it's not defined.
   - Regular and rational functions are used to study the geometry and topology of algebraic varieties.
2. **Morphisms**:

   - A morphism in algebraic geometry is a structure-preserving map between algebraic varieties. It's a more general notion than a function.
   - Formally, a morphism (f: V \rightarrow W) between algebraic varieties (V) and (W) is a map that associates to each point (P) in (V) a point (f(P)) in (W), such that there exist polynomial functions (f_1, \ldots, f_m) defined on open subsets of (W) such that the composition of (f) with the projection map from (W) to its affine space is given by (f_i \circ f) for each (i).
   - In simpler terms, a morphism preserves the algebraic structure of the varieties involved. It's defined globally on the entire variety.
   - Morphisms are fundamental in algebraic geometry for studying maps between varieties, including embeddings, projections, and more.

In summary, while functions describe local behavior on algebraic varieties, morphisms describe global structure-preserving maps between them. Both concepts are crucial in algebraic geometry for understanding the geometric properties and relationships between algebraic varieties.

Comment: Unfortunately, your sense of morphism is very specific and, in the answer, not phrased in  a categorical manner. This doesn't really touch on the categorical question. You could say that there is a category of classical algebraic varieties and morphisms defined in this way... but eh, the morphisms really are just special types of functions on the point-sets, so this is exactly the kind of thing the op is worried about. If anything, we need examples where the morphisms are not just special kinds of function