# Is a morphism a special case of a function?

Tags: functions, morphism

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism states that

> In mathematics, particularly in category theory, a morphism is a structure-preserving map from one mathematical structure to another one of the same type.

while a [Mathematical structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure)

> is a set endowed with some additional features on the set (e.g. an operation, relation, metric, or topology).

It seems to me that a morphism is a special case of a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)), which

> is a binary relation between two sets that associates each element of the first set to exactly one element of the second set.

because the function does not preserve any structure in general.

However, [How is a morphism different from a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000595/how-is-a-morphism-different-from-a-function) suggests that a morphism is the more general thing.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Refer to Section 3.5 of Herrlich and Strecker's *Category Theory,* offering examples of absract categories. Two might be of interest to you: the category of sets and relations has as  objects sets and morphisms between sets as the relations between them; the category of $R$-matrices, $R$ a commutative ring, whose objects are positive integers with morphisms between integers $m,n$ the $n \times m$ matrices with entries in $R.$

Comment: The Wikipedia is just wrong about the meaning of the term "morphism" in category theory. The concept of a morphism in category theory was motivated by the idea of structure-preserving map, but is not restricted to the original motivating examples.

Comment: @RobArthan I wouldn't say it is wrong. The OP's quotation for "morphism" is taken from the first sentence of the article which is purely motivational.

Comment: @PaulFrost The first sentence of the Wikipedia article is just wrong: it says that a morphism in category theory is a **map** which (following the links) it defines to be a function of some kind. As I am sure we both know, there are many interesting categories in which the morphisms can't usefully be identified with functions.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, we both know that. But the link for *map* says "In mathematics, a map is often used as a synonym for a function, but may also refer to some generalizations" and later explains "Maps as functions" and "As morphisms". I do not claim that Wikipedia is a great source, but it not really wrong.

Comment: @RobArthan But I agree that it may be misleading. The question demonstrates it.